# Inline Array Annotation - Why two $scopes are used for this code

Tags: angularjs, dependency-injection

I'm going through Angular JS Documentation. I'm not able to figure out one line that I mentioned in the below code. Can anyone explain ?

**script.js**:

```
angular.module('scopeExample', [])
.controller('MyController', ['$scope', function($scope) { // This line
  $scope.username = 'World';

  $scope.sayHello = function() {
    $scope.greeting = 'Hello ' + $scope.username + '!';
  };
}]);
```

**index.html**:

```
<div ng-controller="MyController">
  Your name:
    <input type="text" ng-model="username">
    <button ng-click='sayHello()'>greet</button>
  <hr>
  {{greeting}}
</div>
```

I didn't understand this:

```
['$scope', function($scope) {}]
```

Here, why two `$scope`s are used.

Comment: The first one is the dependency inject part of the code using inline annotation, while the second one is the actual parameter that needs to be provided to the function in order for  $scope to not be undefined. Better exmplanation here: http://anandmanisankar.com/posts/angularjs-dependency-injection-demystified/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Angular JS - Inline Array Annotation

Its used to avoid problems on minification.
After minification the code looks like:

```
['$scope', function(a) {}]
```

So Angular knows which dependencies to inject.

Otherwise it would look like

```
function(a){}
```

after minification and angular did not know which dependency is meant.

You will find more information in the AngularJS Docs (Dependency Injection)
https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di

Answer (score 0):

With the help of [Michael](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7964627/michael), I found this on Angular JS Docs.

[Inline Array Annotation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di)

> This is the preferred way to annotate application components. This is
>   how the examples in the documentation are written.
>
> For example:
>
> ```
> someModule.controller('MyController', ['$scope', 'greeter', function($scope, greeter) {
>   // ...
> }]);
> ```
>
> Here we pass an array whose elements consist of a list of strings (the
>   names of the dependencies) followed by the function itself.
>
> When using this type of annotation, take care to keep the annotation
>   array in sync with the parameters in the function declaration.

Comment: Actually the preferred way is to add [ngAnnotate](https://github.com/schmod/babel-plugin-angularjs-annotate) to the toolchain. Inline array annotation is repetitive and error prone.